# Replace all surnames following 'Mr' prefix using bash script

Tags: string, bash, shell, replace

I have a csv file where each line contains a person's name like this.

```
| 11th October  | 06 6606 1161 | Mr Bean is 43 years old. Mr Bean likes apples. |
```

My goal is to write a bash script to replace the surnames in the file with a new surname.

So for example with a script `replace_surname.sh` -

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -z $1 ]
then
    #replace surname following 'Mr' with $1
fi
```

I'd expect, given the above csv and the command `replace_surname.sh Smith`

```
| 11th October  | 06 6606 1161 | Mr Smith is 43 years old. Mr Smith likes apples. |
```

What I've tried -

```
sed -i 's/^Mr .*$/Mr PacMan/' test.csv
```

And a few other from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66878/how-can-i-replace-text-after-a-specific-word-using-sed)
Which doesn't affect the file at all.

I'm a bit stuck and my csv file has hundreds of records so I wouldn't like to do it all by hand! Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: `sed 's/Mr [^ ]+/Mr Smith/g' file`?

Comment: What if people have multiple surnames?

Comment: Your script isn't doing any replacements because the `^` in `s/^Mr` is telling sed to only match `Mr` at the start of the line while you need to match mid-line and the `.*$` is telling sed to match til the end of the line while you need to only match til the end of the word.

Comment: [Falsehoods about Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and other [awesome falsehoods](https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  new_surname="$1"
  sed -i "s/Mr\s\+\(\w\+\)/Mr ${new_surname}/g" /tmp/mr
fi
```

that is if the old surname is 1 word

Regex can be further improved, but you should get the idea

Comment: I added the whole script, so there's no confusion.

Comment: To get some useful hints paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: "No issues detected!" in  shellcheck.net

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sed for `-i` and since you need GNU sed you could add `-E` so you don't need some of the backslashes in your regexp and you could add a word boundary so you don't match on `Mr` mid-word - `sed -Ei "s/\<Mr\s+(\w+)/...`